# "Sessions with Event" metric in GA is wierd

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using GA Android SDK v3 to track app utilization.
I found the metric "Sessions with Event" is wierd.

For example, userA report following hits in one session:
1. appview(screen1)
2. appview(screen2)
3. event(category=goto_store)
4. event(category=purchase)

I saw the custom report shows:

dimens="event category", metrics="sessions with event"
goto_store,   1
purchase,   0

It looks like it count the "sessions with event" to the 1st event in session.
It is reasonable??

I would like to know how many sessions with purchase event
When I create a custom report with dimem=appname, metric=session with event and filter 'event_category exact match "purchase"', I got metric of session with event equal to be zero....

This metric is not intuitive...

Kevin Kuei

Comment: Interesting. I knew there was definitely a problem because the math doesn't add up on my custom report. For an event based custom report I can see 8 users, but only 0 or 1 sessions with event. This should have a bunch better label.

Comment: Did you ever figure something out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions With Event is hit-level data that only fires once for *any* event, within a session.  In your example, getting 0 means that you have triggered some other (possibly unrelated) event in the same session.

To get sessions with Purchase event, you will probably need to create a custom segment.  See here for [a good explanation of Sessions With Event]

Comment: did you probably forget to add a link? The last paragraph seems to make little sense :)

Comment: Missing link is in the markdown [a good explanation of Sessions With Event](http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-events/). It's just not rendered due to a mishap in formattting.